# Create a triangle using 3 seek-bars in Android-Studio

Tags: android, xml, seekbar, triangulation

In Android Studio, I want to create an equilateral triangle inside a simple activity using 3 seek-bars as you can see in the following image:

[image: equilateral triangle]

I want to know if it is possible to do this by using XML.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* wanted to do this I'd suggest you subclass `ViewGroup` and override the `onDraw()` method.

Take each child (the three `SeekBar` views) and apply a rotation on each of them based on what index the child view is.

Honestly though you're trying to force the existing UI items to do something they're not really designed to do. You're better off building a completely custom `View` from scratch.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I want controlling each segment of the triangle. to get multiple shapes. like this one:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/lSpSX.jpg
My goal is not to draw numbers but other more complex shapes. I just want to understanding the principle.